# TFS Folder Mapping

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Online. I am having a problem with mapping some of my projects to the correct folders. For some reason, several end up in a folder with my project name.

My class library project is located in ~/PlatformSupport/AdobeBusinessCatalyst/AdobeBusinessCatalyst.Core. What is it located under ~/CloudCartConnector/AdobeBusinessCatalyst.Core in my source control? Everytime I delete the Cloud Cart Connector folder, it removes my AdobeBusinessCatalyst project. I want to remove the CloudCartConnector folder and map all those projects into the ~/PlatformSupport folder. How can I accomplish this?

[image: Workspaces Mapping]

[image]

Comment: What do your workspace mappings look like?  Can you paste a screenshot from the workspaces dialog?

Comment: I would blow that entire workspace away and create a new one from the root.

Comment: OK, I just created a new one.